# Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. error

Tags: string, typescript, types, typescript-never

What I wanna do is so simple.

In the example below,

```
interface InterfaceA { a: string, b: number }
interface InterfaceB { c: keyof InterfaceA }

const testMethod = (test: InterfaceB) => {
      const TestObject: InterfaceA = { a: '', b: 1 }

      TestObject[test.c] = 
    }
```

causes 'Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'' error.

I thought that test.c can be assigned in TestObject since c is the key of Interface A.

How can I make things work?

Comment: could you please edit your question to include a complete and verifiable example. What you've currently provided isn't enough for us to help you. Using the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) you can include a link to a working example in your question.

Comment: @Olian04 Thank u for your advice! I edited my question with a simpler one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving this error because the type of `test.c` can not be narrowed down any more than `keyof InterfaceA`. In other words, if we try to assign to `TestObject[test.c]` typescript wont be able to determine if we need to assign a `string` or a `number`. So it determines that the type must be all valid types at the same time, in this case `number & string`. However no value can be both a `number` and a `string` at the same time, so the resulting type ends up being `never` (See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UB2BXAtgIwgJygMigGdhsBLJAcwG4g) for an example).

We can solve this by helping typescript narrow down the actual type of `test.c` like this:

```
interface InterfaceA { 
    a: string, 
    b: number
}
interface InterfaceB { 
    c: keyof InterfaceA
}

const testMethod = (test: InterfaceB) => {
    const TestObject: InterfaceA = { a: '', b: 1 }

    switch (test.c) {
        case 'a':
            TestObject[test.c] = 'foo';
            break;
        case 'b':
            TestObject[test.c] = 42;
            break;
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBBZBvZAKGROTgC5kBnMKUAcwBojTkAjSkAVwFs3pCAX0KhIsRCnRisEAEL4WpBJQDWEAJ4B7GGgzicQwoQSaQNZJBoBZCGAAWmgCbIAvMgAUlsJSmYJsgEpXAD58YiVTcwAVCBoAeTYAKwgEb11pCVw3AgpkAHI85g5kAEZkYXCSKgB3YDAEOw8vADoEILxK1mQEOCoUPLg88k6u0hj4pJSwAG0WhABdV3yYTU08gG4R0fYoCDgVTe3u3v62Ia3R8bAE5NTZ2LBWxbcAFgAmQ6PSNl39z5JhIIgA)